# Is stacking encryption a good idea for a file system?

Tags: disk-encryption

Somewhat related to a previous [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18087/2944), is stacking encryption under and via file systems a good idea?

For example, [dm-crypt](/questions/tagged/dm-crypt) for the device, and then eCryptfs or [veracrypt](/questions/tagged/veracrypt) for the file system.

If it's not a good idea, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: The answer to your question is fundamentally the same as the answer to the previous question. Using one good cipher is enough, adding more won't help with security and will slow things down.

Comment: @ztk - it is different: the previous question is looking at it form a single user perspective. This question is looking at it from a *system* perspective (whereon, of course, there could be multiple users)

Comment: Encrypting parts of the filesystem with veracypt will protect only those parts (opposed to the whole filesystem with dm-crypt), but it will enable you to decrypt them independently. The later can be useful in a multiuser scenario when the computer is shared between users and the 2 sessions are never used at the same time. If you are in this multiuser scenario, using dm-cypt will add value by better protecting your computer when turned off. Otherwise, you are better protected by only using dm-crypt.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward - can you expand that into a sourced answer?