# Multiple encryption

Tags: encryption

my threat model is this:

I need to encrypt some private data. I am currently using VeraCrypt for that. But I know that in the future, some flaws can be found in certrain encryption algorithm (like DES for example) or in their implementation (alleged backdoor in BitLocker and so on...). That's why I'm looking for a "second pillar" to further secure my data by using another program (similar to VeraCrypt), that should ideally be:

1) Open source and audited (but it doesn't have to be, maybe even paid version is an option).

2) Similar to VeraCrypt (first I create an encrypted containter with the VeraCrypt, then I want to encrypt that containter with another program).

3) Offer different algorithm(s) and hash(ses) than VeraCrypt.

I hope that my question makes sense.

I would also love to hear your opinion about wethever should I use AES-Twofish-Serpent or Serpent-Twofish-AES in VeraCryp. I feel like the order doesn't matter at all, but still, help me decide, please :D

Lastly, what hash algorithms do you consider to be the most secure? I currently use  Whirlpool.

It seems that BCArchive maybe what I'm looking for, but it's not an open source. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is multiple encryption a good idea?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to layer disk-encryption?  And is it disk-encryption to be used on the entire drive while it's in normal use, like BitLocker and the other things you mentioned, or do you just want to encrypt an archive?

Comment: Beyond that, it'd help to clarify the use-case.  I mean, if you're looking for disk-encryption, then a huge problem is the implementation: how do you get your computer to actually use the algorithm you select?  I mean, it feels easy enough to say, "_Sure, use AES_" or whatever, but how to make that work seems like the hard part.